# Grid inside scroll viewer not working

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have added a grid control (I have added about 20 rows, each row contains 2 columns and each of them having text blocks as a child, and I am setting RowHeight as Auto) on top of scroll viewer. It's scrolling but not showing the full content of the grid. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue will be that the framework can't determine the overall height to allocate to the control. Try setting the explicit height of the scrollviewer and/or the grid (if you can).

**Update** 
Please post your exact code. (Or, at least code which recreates the issue.)

The following code is my understanding of what you've described but does not create the behaviour you are experiencing

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <controls:PivotItem Header="first">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}"  Text="A1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="A2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="B1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="B2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="C1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="C2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="D1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="D2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="E1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="E2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="F1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="F2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="G1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="G2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="H1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="H2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="I1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="I2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="J1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextHugeStyle}" Text="J2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" />
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Comment: i am doing following stuff.i am adding panorama on top of a grid and content for panorama, canvas i am putting on top of stack panel and that stack panel i am putting on scroll view and that scroll view i am adding on grid, this grid is content of the panorama.it works fine for the panorama but with pivot it is not scrolling properly. and also for each canvas i am setting height also what may be the issue.

Comment: @gusaindpk it might be easier if you showed that code rather than trying to explain it

Comment: In simple words, am using a grid where am adding textblocks and am adding this grid to a scrollview. And setting the grid as a pivot item. but it is not scrolling properly. when am doing the same in panorama the scrolling works fine.

Comment: thanks i took reference from your code i found the issue if i was setting first base grid row height to auto it was not working fine for pivot and scroll view but panorama it was working, so i have removed the row height for the pivot and now it is working fine Thanks a lot i was really struggling for this.